# Определение серийного номера HDD (Serial Number)

Tags: c#

Всем привет, пытаюсь программно определить серийный номер HDD. В результате получил 2 разных значения:

- с использованием WMI из командной строки (команда **`wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`**)
- с использованием WMI через ManagementObject (экземпляр WMI) в проекте C#

.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new 
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

foreach (ManagementObject hdd in searcher.Get())
    Console.WriteLine(hdd["SerialNumber"]);
```

В первом случае возвращается значение **`9WJ16TH7`**, во втором - **`2020202020202020202020205739314a54363748`**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как исправить ошибку в коде C#.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вместо Win32_PhysicalMedia использовать Win32_DiskDrive (в Vista и далее первый заменен вторым). Протестируй на разных операционных системах. Второй вариант: строка которую ты получаешь в приложении - это последовательность ASCII кодов символов. То есть теперь твоя задача правильно переконвертировать ее в удобоваримый вид.

Comment: Забавно :)


    php -r '$str="2020202020202020202020205739314a54363748"; while($str != "") { echo chr(hexdec(substr($str, 0, 2))); $str = substr($str, 2); } echo "\n";'
                W91JT67H

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с командой

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber
```

может и не работать: там может просто не быть свойства SerialNumber. Это проверяется командой:

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET /?
```

Вместо нее можно также извлечь данные из `Win32_PhysicalMedia`

```
wmic PATH Win32_PhysicalMedia GET SerialNumber
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, хотел наградить 20 очками и первый и второй ответ, но на второй, к сожалению, не хватило так как не знал правила награждения( Оба ответа очень помогли, разобрался!

Comment: Лучше не награждайте, а голосуйте и принимайте.